# Resistance from $I$-$V$ graph

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, potential

[image]

I thought that the answer was obviously A as the gradient remains constant...however, the answer is B...who so?

Comment: Whoever wrote the question is using "resistance" to mean the equivalent resistance rather than the differential resistance. You were answering in terms of the differential resistance. In most (but not all) practical situations, the differential resistance is more important, and your answer is preferred.

Comment: The curve you show is roughly what you expect for the I-V characteristics of a (semiconductor) diode. For pd's across the diode less than $V_0$ (approximately 0.7 V for Si), the effective resistance is $\infty$, and the diode doesn't conduct. For pd's more than $V_0$ the diode conducts. As mentioned by Farcher sometimes the incremental resistance is defined. Typically this would be the effective resistance when the pd across the diode varies and is the effective resistance to the varying pd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remembering that resistance = $\frac V I$ work the resistance at $I=1$ and $I=2$.

[image]

For the resistance to be constant the current-voltage characteristic must be a straight line and go through the origin.

There is another parameter which is useful in some instances and that is called the incremental resistance $\frac {\Delta V} {\Delta I}$ which is related to the gradient of the graph.  In this case the incremental resistance is constant at 1 ohm.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! Really appreciate your effort.